# How to simulate a button click on a web page using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape a web site that waits for a button click from a user. I could not find the proper button to cause selenium to do the click. Here is the web page before the click. It is a simple web page so it is not long. I see in the body the following HTML:

```
<div id="startStopBtn" onclick="startStop()" class=""></div>
```

and in the header there is a function

```
startStop()
```

but I could not figure out how to initiate it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no">
<title>ITC Speedtest</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html,body{
        border:none; padding:0; margin:0;
        background:#fff;
        color:#1e73be;
    }
    body{
        text-align:center;
        font-family:"Roboto",sans-serif;
    }
    h1{
        color:#1e73be;
    }
    #startStopBtn{
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0 auto;
        color:#6060AA;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
        border:0.15em solid #6060FF;
        border-radius:0.3em;
        transition:all 0.3s;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        width:8em; height:3em;
        line-height:2.7em;
        cursor:pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    #startStopBtn:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    #startStopBtn.running{
        background-color:#FF3030;
        border-color:#FF6060;
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    #startStopBtn:before{
        content:"Start";
    }
    #startStopBtn.running:before{
        content:"Abort";
    }
    #test{
        margin-top:2em;
        margin-bottom:12em;
    }
    div.testArea{
        display:inline-block;
        width:16em;
        height:12.5em;
        position:relative;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    div.testName{
        position:absolute;
        top:0.1em; left:0;
        width:100%;
        font-size:1.4em;
        z-index:9;
    }
    div.meterText{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:1.55em; left:0;
        width:100%;
        font-size:2.5em;
        z-index:9;
    }
    div.meterText:empty:before{
        content:"0.00";
    }
    div.unit{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:2em; left:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:9;
    }
    div.testArea canvas{
        position:absolute;
        top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;
        z-index:1;
    }
    div.testGroup{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    @media all and (max-width:65em){
        body{
            font-size:1.5vw;
        }
    }
    @media all and (max-width:40em){
        body{
            font-size:0.8em;
        }
        div.testGroup{
            display:block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function I(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var meterBk="#E0E0E0";
var dlColor="#6060AA",
    ulColor="#309030",
    pingColor="#AA6060",
    jitColor="#AA6060";
var progColor="#EEEEEE";

//CODE FOR GAUGES
function drawMeter(c,amount,bk,fg,progress,prog){
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var dp=window.devicePixelRatio||1;
    var cw=c.clientWidth*dp, ch=c.clientHeight*dp;
    var sizScale=ch*0.0055;
    if(c.width==cw&&c.height==ch){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    }else{
        c.width=cw;
        c.height=ch;
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle=bk;
    ctx.lineWidth=16*sizScale;
    ctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height-58*sizScale,c.height/1.8-ctx.lineWidth,-Math.PI*1.1,Math.PI*0.1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle=fg;
    ctx.lineWidth=16*sizScale;
    ctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height-58*sizScale,c.height/1.8-ctx.lineWidth,-Math.PI*1.1,amount*Math.PI*1.2-Math.PI*1.1);
    ctx.stroke();
    if(typeof progress !== "undefined"){
        ctx.fillStyle=prog;
        ctx.fillRect(c.width*0.3,c.height-16*sizScale,c.width*0.4*progress,4*sizScale);
    }
}
function mbpsToAmount(s){
    return 1-(1/(Math.pow(1.3,Math.sqrt(s))));
}
function msToAmount(s){
    return 1-(1/(Math.pow(1.08,Math.sqrt(s))));
}

//SPEEDTEST AND UI CODE
var w=null; //speedtest worker
var data=null; //data from worker
function startStop(){
    if(w!=null){
        //speedtest is running, abort
        w.postMessage('abort');
        w=null;
        data=null;
        I("startStopBtn").className="";
        initUI();
    }else{
        //test is not running, begin
        w=new Worker('speedtest_worker.min.js');
        w.postMessage('start'); //Add optional parameters as a JSON object to this command
        I("startStopBtn").className="running";
        w.onmessage=function(e){
            data=e.data.split(';');
            var status=Number(data[0]);
            if(status>=4){
                //test completed
                I("startStopBtn").className="";
                w=null;
                updateUI(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
//this function reads the data sent back by the worker and updates the UI
function updateUI(forced){
    if(!forced&&(!data||!w)) return;
    var status=Number(data[0]);
//  I("ip").textContent=data[4];
    I("dlText").textContent=(status==1&&data[1]==0)?"...":data[1];
    drawMeter(I("dlMeter"),mbpsToAmount(Number(data[1]*(status==1?oscillate():1))),meterBk,dlColor,Number(data[6]),progColor);
    I("ulText").textContent=(status==3&&data[2]==0)?"...":data[2];
    drawMeter(I("ulMeter"),mbpsToAmount(Number(data[2]*(status==3?oscillate():1))),meterBk,ulColor,Number(data[7]),progColor);
    I("pingText").textContent=data[3];
    drawMeter(I("pingMeter"),msToAmount(Number(data[3]*(status==2?oscillate():1))),meterBk,pingColor,Number(data[8]),progColor);
}
function oscillate(){
    return 1+0.02*Math.sin(Date.now()/100);
}
//poll the status from the worker (this will call updateUI)
setInterval(function(){
    if(w) w.postMessage('status');
},200);
//update the UI every frame
window.requestAnimationFrame=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||(function(callback,element){setTimeout(callback,1000/60);});
function frame(){
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    updateUI();
}
frame(); //start frame loop
//function to (re)initialize UI
function initUI(){
    drawMeter(I("dlMeter"),0,meterBk,dlColor,0);
    drawMeter(I("ulMeter"),0,meterBk,ulColor,0);
    drawMeter(I("pingMeter"),0,meterBk,pingColor,0);
    I("dlText").textContent="";
    I("ulText").textContent="";
    I("pingText").textContent="";
//  I("ip").textContent="";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ITC Speedtest</h1>
<div id="startStopBtn" onclick="startStop()" class=""></div>
<div id="test">
    <div class="testGroup">
        <div class="testArea">
            <div class="testName">Download</div>
            <canvas id="dlMeter" class="meter" width="223" height="174"></canvas>
            <div id="dlText" class="meterText">162.74</div>
            <div class="unit">Mbps</div>
        </div>
        <div class="testArea">
            <div class="testName">Upload</div>
            <canvas id="ulMeter" class="meter" width="223" height="174"></canvas>
            <div id="ulText" class="meterText">9.85</div>
            <div class="unit">Mbps</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testGroup">
        <div class="testArea">
            <div class="testName">Ping</div>
            <canvas id="pingMeter" class="meter" width="223" height="174"></canvas>
            <div id="pingText" class="meterText">23.83</div>
            <div class="unit">ms</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ipArea">
        IP Address: <span id="ip">100.103.124.12</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(initUI,100);</script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#startStopBtn[onclick^='startStop']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='ITC Speedtest']//following-sibling::div[@id='startStopBtn' and starts-with(@onclick, 'startStop')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#startStopBtn[onclick^='startStop']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h1[text()='ITC Speedtest']//following-sibling::div[@id='startStopBtn' and starts-with(@onclick, 'startStop')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Selenium -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("URL")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH_BUTTON")
button.click()
```

Put in your URL, Place of chrome in your PC, and XPATH of the button.

Comment: I wanted to do it but I could not find the button so I do not know it's XPath

Comment: I tried the above code with xpath of 'startStopBtn' but got an error
 "'list' object has no attribute 'click'"

Comment: It looks like my xpath is wrong but I do not know how to set it right